# Ensure the proper order of subsequent HTTP ajax calls in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-service

Assume we have a super simple search form with autocomplete which triggers a $http.get() request on keyup/keypress:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="keyword" ng-change="makeRequest()">
```

and

```
$scope.makeRequest = function() {
   $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
      // update the typeahead list here.
   });
}
```

What is the easiest way to maintain order in which the responses are being passed in? Due to a varying latency earlier results often come last which confuses user. 
I'm looking for something order than a straight debounce which would prevent a request from being made under a certain keystroke interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the latest request and ignore responses unless it's from the latest...

```
var latestRequest = 0;
$scope.makeRequest = function() {
   var thisRequest = ++latestRequest;
   $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
      if (thisRequest === latestRequest) {
        // update the typeahead
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: I've figured this is the easiest and the most straightforward way to do this combined with a time interval check (just to give API a rest a bit). Ended up checking the latest keyword in params, not the query count itself: `$http.get(url, params).then(function(res.data) { if(params.keyword === latestKeyword) {  $scope.results = res.data });`